# Obtener atributo src con BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

mi codigo esta asi:

```
for a in soup.find_all('img',attrs={'class': 'lazy no_image'}):

    print(a)
```

y obtengo lo siguiente:

```
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/1t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/2t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/3t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/4t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/5t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/6t.jpg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazy no_image" data-
src="//i.hentaifox.com/002/1078986/7t.jpg"/>
```

He buscado y probado pero no logro sacar el atributo src. como lo podria hacer?

NOTA: uso bs4 y python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias incluir el html para poder ser más especificos y reproducir el problema. No obstante, tienes dos opciones:

- **Usar un [selector css](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):**

  ```
  thumbnails = soup.select('img.lazy.no_image')

  for thumbnail in thumbnails:
      url = thumbnail['data-src']
      print(url)
  ```
- **Usar expresiones regulares ([re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))** sobre tu salida actual:

  ```
  import re

  patt = re.compile('src="(.*)".*/>')

  for a in soup.find_all('img',attrs={'class': 'lazy no_image'}):
      url = re.findall(patt, str(a))[0]
      print(url)
  ```

Comment: gracias, me funciono con la primera opcion la segunda no la conocia, la probare para aprender algo nuevo